# Cloning SharePoint Modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, pnp-powershell

I have a SharePoint Modern site that I want to clone. I want to create almost like a "staging" version of my modern site. Which will have all my lists and even the items in those lists if that's possible.

In SharePoint classic I was able to create a template option, but that doesn't seem possible anymore with Modern. I ran across this article here: http://webbrewers.com/modern-sharepoint-create-a-site-template-yes-communications-sites-too/?i=1 and when following I got an error saying page can not be found.

What is the best way to "clone"/duplicate a SharePoint modern site with all it's lists and data?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, as i understand your situation, what you are looking for is a provisioning service.

This can be achieved with PnP Provisioning engine and Site Designs.
Since the above are by themselves two huge topics within the sharepoint community, i would advise you reading throught [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/provisioning-sites-from-site-designs-using-pnp-powershell-pros-consof-using/) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview) .

I believe that a [Site Script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview#anatomy-of-a-site-script) would do the job that you are looking to accomplish

Comment: Site Script can provision artifacts. The only question is can it  clone a site? Can it even clone a page or a library?